# what is the alternative to autoboxing in Java?

Tags: java

As any Java programmer knows, you can’t put an int (or other primitive value) into a collection. Collections can only hold object references, so you have to box primitive values into the appropriate wrapper class (which is Integer in the case of int). When you take the object out of the collection, you get the Integer that you put in; if you need an int, you must unbox the Integer using the intValue method. All of this boxing and unboxing is a pain, and clutters up your code. The autoboxing and unboxing feature automates the process, eliminating the pain and the clutter.

Are there other ways to convert primitive types to non-primitive analogs?

Comment: Why would you need another way of converting primitives to their corresponding wrapper classes and viceversa?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but one thing that comes to mind is using primitive arrays instead of collection objects (assuming your collection is *only* that type).

Comment: There is **no** need to write ` intValue`. The compiler will do **auto**boxing.

Comment: you've already answer it `auto-boxing` and `auto-unboxing` so no need to look further because there is no other one

Comment: 1. it is question to interview for the job

Answer (score 1):

No need of `intValue()` at all:

```
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(new Integer(70));
        int x = list.get(0) + 600;
        if (x > 800) {
            x = new Integer(80);
        }
```

(but there can be some [pitfalls ...](https://effective-java.com/2010/05/the-advantages-and-traps-of-autoboxing/))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to go away from autoboxing and unboxing features. But this is how it looks like without using those.

```
    int number = 5;
    Integer num = new Integer(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `List` alternative that actually holds primitive data types instead of knowing that you can avoid `intValue` calls (it seems like you already know this near the end of your question's text).

In the Java Class Library there is no `List` implementation that store primitive data types directly but third party libraries essentially do support this, for example [Apache Commons' ArrayIntList](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-primitives/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/primitives/ArrayIntList.html).

The good news is that it's planned to allow for primitive types to be used as generic type arguments for Java 10. However Java 10 will arrive sometime around 2018.